# What is the use of queueSizeRejectionThreshold in Hystrix when I already have max.Queue.poolSize?

Tags: hystrix, blockingqueue

Why we need `queueSizeRejectionThreshold` in Hystrix apart from `maxQueueSize`?

By definition, `queueSizeRejectionThreshold <= maxQueueSize`. But I am not getting why not to reject thread when `maxQueueSize` becomes full, why to introduce the term `queueSizeRejectionThreshold`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/configuration#queueSizeRejectionThreshold) explains the reason why you may need `queueSizeRejectionThreshold`:

> This property exists because the maxQueueSize of a BlockingQueue cannot be dynamically changed and we want ***to allow you to dynamically change the queue size*** that affects rejections.

If you don't want to change the queue size dynamically (in run time) simply set `maxQueueSize = queueSizeRejectionThreshold`.